# Python sockets suddenly timing out?

Tags: python, api, sockets, ssl, gmail

I came back today to an old script I had for logging into Gmail via SSL. The script worked fine last time I ran it (several months ago) but now it dies immediately with:

```
<urlopen error The read operation timed out>
```

If I set the timeout (no matter how long), it dies even more immediately with:

```
<urlopen error The connect operation timed out>
```

The latter is reproducible with:

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30000)
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('www.google.com', 443))
ssl = socket.ssl(sock)
```

returning:

```
socket.sslerror: The connect operation timed out
```

but I can't seem to reproduce the former and, after much stepping thru the code, I have no clue what's causing any of this.

Comment: What version of Python is it?

Comment: Please specify more information. I can not reproduce your problem.

Comment: Platform would help too.

Answer (score 2):

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(30000)
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('www.google.com', 443))
ssl = socket.ssl(sock)
ssl.server()
--> '/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=www.google.com'
```

It works just fine. I can't reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

www.google.com is not accessible by HTTPS.  It redirects to insecure HTTP.  To get to mail, you should be going go https://mail.google.com

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is whether you need to connect via an HTTP proxy (in which case direct connections bypassing the proxy will likely time out). Run Wireshark and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is no timeout connecting to `www.google.com`, but Python 3.x now offers the `ssl` module so OP's sample code won't work.

Here's something similar that will work with current versions of Python:

```py
import ssl
import socket
from pprint import pprint


hostname = 'www.google.org'
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        pprint(ssock.getpeercert()['subject'])
```

Which produces:

```py
((('countryName', 'US'),),
 (('stateOrProvinceName', 'California'),),
 (('localityName', 'Mountain View'),),
 (('organizationName', 'Google LLC'),),
 (('commonName', 'misc.google.com'),))
```

Read more about the ssl module here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html